# How do I check that all the elements of an array satisfy a condition?

Tags: arrays, ruby, conditional-statements

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  How do I check if all elements of my array satisfy a condition?  I have

```
cond = true
arr.each do |e|
  if e.nil? || e.to_i < 5
    cond = false
    break
   end
end
```

but I feel like there's a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can rewrite that as

```
arr.all? { |e| e.to_i >= 5 }
```

Comment: Yep, it's great :)

Comment: The question is, "How do I check if all elements of my array satisfy a condition?".  Your answer is a solution to the specific example given by the OP, rather than a general solution, so it's of limited usefulness. Suppose, for example, that all you know is that `arr` is an array of any objects, `obj`, which might include `nil`, and you are given a condition in the form of a method `m` that takes `obj` as an argument and returns `true` or `false`.  Then you could write `arr.all? { |obj| !obj.nil? && m(obj) }`. This comment applies to other answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I check if all elements of my array satisfy a condition?

Use `all?`. For example:

```
[1, 2, 3].all? { |i| i < 4 } #=> true
```

Comment: It looks like `i` can be nil.